# How to obfuscate WAR with maven plugin for Proguard?

Tags: java, proguard, war, proguard-maven-plugin

How do I obfuscate a WAR using proguard? I have one WAR which contains multiple dependencies as JARs inside and I want to obfuscate only my codebase, by filtering by package name (leaving the rest of dependencies intact).

I'm getting thousands of warnings. How do I even do this? Am I supposed to skim through every single one of them and check if they have to be looked at / suppressed? am I missing a piece of configuration?

why am I getting warnings, shouldn't all dependencies be there?

java version is 8

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${proguard.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <proguardVersion>${proguard.version}</proguardVersion>
        <injar>${project.build.finalName}.war</injar>
        <outjar>${project.build.finalName}.obfuscated.war</outjar>
        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
        <options>
            <option>-dontnote !my.package**</option>

            <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers</option>
            <option>-dontshrink</option>
            <option>-dontoptimize</option>

            <option>-adaptclassstrings</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original annotations and etc. Otherwise all we be removed from files.-->
            <option>-keepattributes
                Signature,
                *Annotation*
            </option>

            <option>-ignorewarnings</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original class files (without obfuscate) in service package-->
            <!-- <option>-keep class com.slm.proguard.example.spring.boot.service { *; }</option>-->
            <!-- This option will save all original interfaces files (without obfuscate) in all packages.-->
            <option>-keep interface !my.package** { *; }</option>
            <option>-keep class !my.package** { *; }</option>
        </options>
        <injarNotExistsSkip>true</injarNotExistsSkip>
        <libs>
            <!--Put here your libraries if required-->
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.guardsquare</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>${proguard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to obfuscate the JAR before building the WAR file. The proguard plugin should be only applied to the .war if it contains classes in the WEB-INF/classes directory.

Comment: What if I want to obfuscate the dependencies as well, do I have to write a proguard configuration for each pom that I pull in? I need to obfuscate every dependant JAR before packaging it into the WAR along with the application but currently struggling with maven. Maybe it's not the best tool for this flow. If you have any pointers I'll gladly listen. :)